# Converting Json response into a unique dataframe

Tags: r, json, data-manipulation, httr

Using tm1 rest api, I could get the data from a post request.

```
  Date: 2018-04-11 14:43
  Status: 201
  Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; charset=utf-8
  Size: 2.86 MB
```

Then I converted this response into a json format using:

```
fromJSON(content(data, type = "text"))
```

Then it appears:

*UPDATE:

Now I installed Jsonlite, and I got an dataframe:

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBE6w.jpg)

Where Hierarchies [[**1**]] and [2](https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py/blob/master/TM1py/Utils/Utils.py) represents 5 column names, and tuples [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBE6w.jpg)] and [[2](https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py/blob/master/TM1py/Utils/Utils.py)] represents rows values of those 5 columns.

The [value] Cells, are the last column that is missing, already in a dataframe format.

But all the variables seems to be as a list, and there is a unique dataframe just appearing on [values].

I have tried:

```
   df_list <- list( df[["Axes"]][["Hierarchies"]], df[["Axes"]][["Tuples"]], df[["Cells"]][["Value"]])
```

However, I don't know exactly how to merge correctly.

In python, this conversion is made using this script:

[Script](https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py/blob/master/TM1py/Utils/Utils.py)

```
 def build_pandas_dataframe_from_cellset(cellset, multiindex=True, sort_values=True):
    """

    :param cellset: 
    :param multiindex: True or False
    :param sort_index: Boolean to control sorting in result DataFrame
    :return: 
    """
    cellset_clean = {}
    for coordinates, cell in cellset.items():
        element_names = element_names_from_element_unqiue_names(coordinates)
        cellset_clean[element_names] = cell['Value']

    dimension_names = tuple([unique_name[1:unique_name.find('].[')] for unique_name in coordinates])

    # create index
    keylist = list(cellset_clean.keys())
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keylist, names=dimension_names)

    # create DataFrame
    values = list(cellset_clean.values())
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=["Values"])

    if not multiindex:
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        if sort_values:
            df.sort_values(inplace=True, by=list(dimension_names))
    return df
```

I would like to do a similar step.

Comment: What R package is the fromJSON function you are using coming from? The jsonlite package version of fromJSON returns a data frame.

Comment: No, I was using other package. I have just installed Jsonlite